# How can I center (both vertically and horizontally) a text within an image, both inside an <a> tag?

Tags: html, css

This is the code I am using. When I position `.thumb-title` as `absolute` with `bottom: 50%` it moves it up relative to it's own height.

```css
.project-thumb {
  position: relative;
}
.thumb-title {
  font: 400 1.5rem'Lato', sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <a class="project-thumb" href="ktc.html">
    <img class="thumb" src="thumbs/thumb-201612t-ktc.jpg">
    <h3 class="thumb-title">Sample text</h3>
  </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the thumb has a known width, then you can use `display:inline-block;`, `vertical-align:middle`, `text-align:center;` and a negative `margin`. This can avoid `absolute` and `transform`.

```css
.project-thumb,
.project-thumb h3 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;/* thumb's width */
  box-sizing: border-box;/* if you add borders or padding*/
  color: initial
}
.thumb {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -150px;/* reduce virtually width to 0 to pull text */
}
.thumb-title {
  z-index: 1;/* make sure it stands on top of img*/
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<a class="project-thumb" href="ktc.html">
  <img class="thumb" src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/aaaaaa/aaaaaa&text=."><!-- 
  mind this white space  for inline-block elements, comment erase it
  --><h3 class="thumb-title">
      Sample text</h3>
</a>
 

<a class="project-thumb" href="ktc.html">
  <img class="thumb" src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/aaaaaa/aaaaaa&text=."><!-- 
  mind this white space  for inline-block elements, comment erase it
  --><h3 class="thumb-title">
      2 lines <br/> of text</h3>
</a>
```

---

**Edit:** looks like you commented another answer where you talked about a flex box ? here a flex version , but only a guess from your real layout & CSS

```css
.project-thumb,
.project-thumb h3 {
  display: inline-flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;/* thumb's width */
  box-sizing: border-box;/* if you add borders or padding*/
  color: initial;
  justify-content:center;
}
.thumb {
  margin-right: -150px;/* reduce virtually width to 0 to pull text */
}
.thumb-title {
  z-index: 1;/* make sure it stands on top of img*/
  margin:auto 0;
}
```

```html
<a class="project-thumb" href="ktc.html">
  <img class="thumb" src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/aaaaaa/aaaaaa&text=."><!-- 
  mind this white space  for inline-block elements, comment erase it
  --><h3 class="thumb-title">
      Sample text</h3>
</a>
<a class="project-thumb" href="ktc.html">
  <img class="thumb" src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/aaaaaa/aaaaaa&text=."><!-- 
  mind this white space  for inline-block elements, comment erase it
  --><h3 class="thumb-title">
      2 lines <br/> of text</h3>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `text-align: center;` on the `.project-thumb` and the `left: 50%;` rule with the `transform: translate(-50%,-50%);` rule for the `.thumb-title` as following:

```css
.project-thumb {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
.thumb-title {
  font: 400 1.5rem'Lato', sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  padding:0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <a class="project-thumb" href="ktc.html">
    <img class="thumb" src="data:image/png;base64,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">
    <h3 class="thumb-title">Sample text</h3>
  </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help! Kind of tested bits and pieces and here's what worked for me:

HTML:

```
<li>
    <a class="project-thumb" href="ktc.html">
        <img class="thumb-img" src="thumbs/thumb-201612t-ktc.jpg">
        <h3 class="thumb-title">Sample text</h3>
   </a>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
.thumb-project {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
}

.thumb-img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

.thumb-title {
font: 400 1.2rem 'Lato', sans-serif;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
bottom: 50%;
text-align: center;
opacity: 0;
}
```